# Method for importing System.Data.Dataset XML file into SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, dataset

**Background**: I am updating scripts in PowerShell that routinely export large amounts of data from a non-MS database to SQL Server on a different host.

On the export side, I have chosen the .NET `System.Data.Dataset` object as the format for the data. The transfer file is created using the `WriteXml` method with the `WriteSchema` option. This approach supports multiple tables and retains database schema information for the receiving server all in a single file.

Per request, a basic `DataSet` file might be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="table1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="col1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="col2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="table2">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="col1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="col2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <table1>
    <col1>tkshrq</col1>
    <col2>6krrtq</col2>
  </table1>
  <table1>
    <col1>k60stu</col1>
    <col2>sqnhp9</col2>
  </table1>
  <table2>
    <col1>6k1thw</col1>
    <col2>n2ocgz</col2>
  </table2>
  <table2>
    <col1>26kmw5</col1>
    <col2>ym3iwd</col2>
  </table2>
</NewDataSet>
```

On the receiving side, I have an import script that utilizes `Write-SqlTableData` to bulk load tables from the `DataSet` file into temporary tables and then run a stored procedure to provide transaction isolation while data moves to the "live" tables.

I am hoping to find a method to directly access the `DataSet` file from within T-SQL so the import can be done by a single stored procedure.

I am aware how to set up linked servers for flat, "rowset" files (CSVs, DataTable, etc) and query them with `OPENROWSET`. But I have not been successful in accessing the multi-tabled `DataSet` file.

I am not interested in changing the transfer file format. It has several desired features and I'd rather deal with a zillion temporary tables than wrangle a zillion transfer files.

I am also aware of third party XML ODBC providers for SQL Server. But third party software is not permissible in this instance.

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample of your Dataset XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using T-SQL and XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()`.

I saved your XML as 'e:\Temp\NewDataSet.xml' file.

SQL Server XML data type can hold up to 2GB size wise.

If the performance of the suggested method is not that good, depending on the volume of the data, it is possible to load the entire XML file into a temporary table with one row and one column.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  col1 VARCHAR(50), col2 VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  col1 VARCHAR(50), col2 VARCHAR(50));

DECLARE @xml XML;

SELECT @xml = XmlDoc   
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'e:\Temp\NewDataSet.xml', SINGLE_BLOB, CODEPAGE='65001') AS Tab(XmlDoc);

INSERT INTO @tbl1 (col1, col2)
SELECT c.value('(col1/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS col1
   , c.value('(col2/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS col2
FROM @xml.nodes('/NewDataSet/table1') AS t(c);

INSERT INTO @tbl2 (col1, col2)
SELECT c.value('(col1/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS col1
   , c.value('(col2/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS col2
FROM @xml.nodes('/NewDataSet/table2') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl1;
SELECT * FROM @tbl2;
```

**Output**

Table1

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID |  col1  |  col2  |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | tkshrq | 6krrtq |
|  2 | k60stu | sqnhp9 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Table2

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID |  col1  |  col2  |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | 6k1thw | n2ocgz |
|  2 | 26kmw5 | ym3iwd |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Nice, @Yitzhak!  I'll play with this and let you know. -thanks

Comment: Thanks, Yitzhak. As asked, this is a good solution so I accept it.  For my purposes, however, I cannot use it.  I need a solution that will import the schema from `DataSet` object as well as the data and was hoping for some means of establishing a linked server to the `DataSet` file such that column typing is implicit in a query.  I am baffled, given that these are both MS domains, that I can find no documentation on how to perform this obvious task.

Comment: @Frobozz, as an alternative solution it is possible to generate `INSERT` statements as a dynamic SQL on the fly from the `<xs:schema>` fragment.

Comment: If it can be wrapped in a transaction and adapt to the source schema changing (which will happen), I am very interested in any example you can offer.

Comment: @Frobozz, Please ask it as a separate new question.